# Apache : client denied by server configuration for some local ressources

Tags: apache

i have some troubles to install local website for development.
I have an "client denied by server configuration"' error for some local ressources like .png or .js
My website have following treepath :
website/files
website/app/local
website/app/share

My mainpage is in app/local and can access to files /files but i have 403 error for files in app/share.
I put "chmod -R 777 www-data" on full website directory so what's wrong ?

[SOLVING]I have another little problem : i can't access to my website with localhost/website but only with localhost/
I have reading some tutos and think my following configuration is right (my apache is 2.2) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName julien.quai13.com
    DocumentRoot /home/julien-quai13/www    
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin julien@andcotransport.com 
    ServerName julien.quai13.com/andcotransport

    DocumentRoot /home/julien-quai13/www/andcotransport
    #<Directory />
    #   Options FollowSymLinks
    #   AllowOverride All
    #</Directory>
    <Directory /home/julien-quai13/www/andcotransport>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this my /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    julien.quai13.com
127.0.1.1    julien-quai13
192.126.0.34 julien.quai13.com
```

Not very important but annoying, i always have problems when i switch of Wamp to Linux.

Thanks for helping (promise i stay on Linux this time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when using vhosts, if apache doesn't match the URL with any server name, it will serve the first one it comes to, if this is the first one, then localhost will map straight to /home/julien-quai13/www/andcotransport

You should set up a virtualhost for default with `DocumentRoot /home/julien-quai13/www` and add a Directory directive for this directory, then localhost/andcotransport will work.

Not sure if this is what you meant to write: `chmod -R 777 www-data` but this is wrong, commands should be `chmod -R 755 /home/julien-quai13/www/andcotransport` and `chown -R julien-quai13:www-data /home/julien-quai13/www/andcotransport`

But permissions wouldn't give you a client denied by server configuration error, this is down to `allow` being set incorrectly.

Also you have defined julien.quai13.com twice in your hosts file.. one points to 127.0.0.1 and another points to 192.126.0.34.. this may be another problem..

Otherwise i'd consider restructuring your vhosts.

Judging by your vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName julien.quai13.com
    DocumentRoot /home/julien-quai13/www    
    <Directory /home/julien-quai13/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't actually need the second vhost unless its under a different domaing, like `andcotransport.julien.quai13.com`  so, just use the default domain and pass everything to `/andcotransport`, if thats how you want to do it...

but make sure all your resources are going to `/andcotransport/files` and `/andcotransport/app/share`  then this should work, unless you have an overriding ACL somewhere which is blocking directories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Yes sorry i mix up the 2 commands when i wrote my question. I retype yours both and it's not working to solve 403 error.

But you solved problems about url, i now access correctly to localhost/website or julien.quai13.com/website

Comment: yes like i say, client denied by server error is down to the allow directive not allowing a certain directory from a certain client.  try adding `Order Allow,Deny` and `allow from all` to the `<Directory />` directive...

Comment: .htaccess in app/ with "order allow,deny
deny from all". Don't have this problems on Windows and on the production server so i never think to looking in this file ><